# AngularJS, multiple promises wait doesn't go well inside multiple ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-ng-include

I'm on a curious problem, i have some hints, but i need yours lights.

Actually, i have a page which contain two ng-include directive, which each other point on another page with a respective controller.
Each nested controller have a refresh icon i control with an ng-class and a $scope variable "refresh":

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh color-blue animation-fade" ng-show="refresh" ng-class="{'fa-spin': refresh==true }"></i>
```

On my main page, when i do an "global action" that will impact all the nested controllers, i $emit multiple event to each of them. Each controller will call an webapi to get some datas.
During the calling, the resfresh icon is activated, so **$scope.refresh** is **true**.

Each controller wait for his promise to resolve to make the **$scope.refresh** to **false**.

But here is the strange problem. Sometimes the refresh icon stay active on one of the nested controllers (or all, or none of them) even if the $scope.models were setted to false.

It occur when the call of the webapi is quick for each controllers. I think the multiple responses are produced at a *nearly* same time and modify the scope when the view is actually refreshed ($apply()) by another nested controller. So angularjs "loose" some events and don't resfresh it.

Am i right ? If yes, what can i do about it ?

I tried to call an **$apply()** at each **$scope.refresh=false** but, AngularJS throw me an exception (*$digest() is already running*). That's logic but, how can i force the **$apply()** safely ?

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

To force the `$apply` safely you can use `$evalAsync` or `$applyAsync` ... this way you will avoid that error because it creates a q. Tho, to be honest I don't think the problem is there if you're using normal $http calls to get the data that automatically triggers the $digest cycle when the promise is finished so anything in the success() callback is safe to propagate in the $scope.

Comment: Indeed, i tried this, and it changed nothing. I don't understand why ng-class don't repercute my model change... What could be the reason ? Maybe the fast value's change ? The $scope.refresh change from false to true and true to false in <20ms..

Comment: The small time interval shouldn't matter. Unfortunately I can't help you unless you provide a fiddle or something similar to be able to see the problem in action.

Comment: I'll try to build one to reproduce the problem quickly. Thanks in advance. :)